# storing email signature on MS Exchange Server via MAPI using C#?

Tags: c#, mapi

is there a way to programatically store email signatures on MS Exchange Server via MAPI using C#?

Answer (score 1):

Email signatures are only stored and applied on the client, not on the server.  They are also not exposed by MAPI on the client.  I have heard of some applications that can help you manage email signatures across your client machines, but I have never used any.